Keyboard Shortcut for "Connect in New Window" in VSCode Remote Explorer Throws Error
I set a keyboard shortcut for the "Connect in New Window" command (remote-explorer.connectToFolderInNewWindow) in the VSCode Remote Explorer.
The keyboard shortcut is displayed correctly when I open the context menu on a remote folder in the Remote Explorer.
But when I select a remote folder and press the shortcut, only an error message pops up:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toUri')

How can I fix this issue to allow connecting to remotes via the keyboard shortcut? Are there alternative solutions to achieve the same functionality?

VSCode version: 1.92.0
OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Remote Extension: 0.112.0

